# Comparing specific columns of 2 lines in a file

Tags: python, file, csv

Check whether 2 lines have same values for 1st and 2nd column in a file, if they does not have then add that line to another 'output' file, if they are same then based on the third column(times stamp), the most recent is added to 'output' file.

The snippet below compares the complete line , and not the columns, how can I do it for columns ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,sys,csv

file_open= sys.argv[1]
    with open (file_open,'r') as f1, open ('output.txt','w+') as f2:

    lines2 = f2.readlines()
    for line in f1:
            if line not in lines2:
                    f2.write(line)
```

## Input

```
1,A,28/04/17 10:57:28.096

3,A,28/04/17 10:57:46.950

1,A,28/04/17 10:59:16.969

3,A,28/04/17 11:02:09.341

4,A,28/04/17 11:03:09.432
```

## Expected output

```
1,A,28/04/17 10:59:16.969

3,A,28/04/17 11:02:09.341

4,A,28/04/17 11:03:09.432
```

Comment: the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module which you import and don't use should let you handle the lines like lists

Comment: could be there more than 2 lines with shared columns?

Comment: @Nullman I know that, a code example could have helped.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, there can be any number of lines.

Comment: why downovote ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are importing the `csv` module, I recommend you use it.

```
import sys 
import csv

seen = set()

file_open = sys.argv[1]
with open(file_open, 'r') as f1, open('output.txt','w') as f2:
    reader = csv.reader(f1)
    writer = csv.writer(f2)

    for line in reader:
        if not len(line): # a quick check to make sure it's a valid line
            continue

        if (line[0], line[1]) not in seen:
            seen.add((line[0], line[1]))
            writer.writerow(line)
```

This code checks to ensure that a line with the same first and second column hasn't already been seen before it writes it. Tuples are hashable so this is simple to do.

Output:

```
1,A,28/04/17 10:57:28.096
3,A,28/04/17 10:57:46.950
4,A,28/04/17 11:03:09.432
```

Comment: @HARSHITKHURANA Cheers, glad to know it helped.

Comment: It does not sort on the basis of time, it keeps the earlier entry instead of the latest one.
It isn't solving the issue.

Comment: perhaps it was apart of the question.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of [@Coldspeed's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44746703/4565943) to use `OrderedDict` to keep the most recent entries as per the timestamp (assuming that the timestamp come out in order).

```
import sys 
import csv

from collections import OrderedDict

history = OrderedDict()

file_open = sys.argv[1]
with open(file_open, 'r') as f1, open('output.txt','w') as f2:
    reader = csv.reader(f1)
    writer = csv.writer(f2)

    for line in reader:
        if not len(line): # valid line check
            continue
        history[(line[0], line[1])] = line[2] # Adds if present, updates if new

    for line in list(history.items()):
        writer.writerow([line[0][0], line[0][1], line[1]])
```

Contents of `output.txt`:

```
1,A,28/04/17 10:59:16.969
3,A,28/04/17 11:02:09.341
4,A,28/04/17 11:03:09.432
```

Comment: thanks, but I dont think that's necessary.
It is beneficial though

Comment: There are more columns as well which are to be printed as it is, but this only prints 3 columns.
How can I change that ?

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `itertools.groupby()` function and `datetime` module (to compare *date* strings):

```
import sys, csv, itertools, datetime, operator

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as in_csv, open('output.csv', 'w') as out_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(in_csv)
    lines = [ max(g, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[2], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S.%f'))
              for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(reader, key=lambda r: (r[0], r[1])), key=operator.itemgetter(0,1))]

    writer = csv.writer(out_csv, lineterminator='\n')
    for l in lines:
        writer.writerow(l)
```

---

***output.csv*** contents:

```
1,A,28/04/17 10:59:16.969
3,A,28/04/17 11:02:09.341
4,A,28/04/17 11:03:09.432
```

Comment: I was trying to understand your solution , but could not get it work..
It throws error : ' ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S.%f' ' , if you could please help.